# Why do this returns a non expected result?

Tags: javascript, reduce

So I'm learning about the reduce method and I write this code...

```js
function getSum(x,y){
  return x+y
  }
var arraySum = function(array) {
  return array.reduce(getSum)
};

arraySum([1,[2,3],[[4]],5])
```

But it actually returns a string of the elements all-together...

I'm actually trying to sum them all... I expected the result to be 15 instead of "12,345"

What's happening? what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Out of curiosity what result did you expect to get?

Comment: You're performing `int + array`. The only way JS knows how to combine these is as strings. For example, `1 + [2]` results in `"12"`. Similarly, `1 + [2,3]` will combine `1 and "2,3"` for a result of `"1,23"`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you're adding actual arrays together, not the content within the arrays. Add a counter, and an incrementational variable like `i` inside the variable `arraySum`, and call the position of `i`, incrementing it every time, it should fix your problem.